# How to create kiosk compatible chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I have a Chrome Packaged App which I wish to deploy and use in a Chrome OS Public Session Kiosk (**Not Single App Kiosk**).

From here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3017014?hl=en

> Public Session Kiosk apps
>
> All hosted Chrome apps and **some packaged apps** are supported as kiosk
>   apps. Here are some popular Public Session

How do I configure my Chrome packaged app to work in a Public Session Kiosk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Spoke to a Sr Deployment Mgr for Chrome OS @ Google, he told me:

Only whitelisted packaged apps are supported in public sessions. In order to be whitelisted Google must review your app for security.

Answer (score 0):

Is this still the case? According to the [support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3017014?hl=en#apps,) looks like it is now supported as long as you use the APIs in the whitelist and use Chrome version 57 and above.

> Starting with Chrome version 57, public sessions supports the remote installation of extensions and packaged apps. To run Chrome apps and extensions in a public session, the app or extension can only declare the following subset of permissions in its manifest. If an app or extension declares a permission not in the list below, such as "cookies", the app or extension won't be installed in a public session.