# How to make my Chrome kiosk app white-listed in Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-os

I have a Chrome kiosk app that runs in full screen when in user session and in single-app kiosk mode. However, it does not run in full screen when in public session mode.

I have seen other third party apps able to run in full screen when in public session mode. By looking into Chromium OS source code, I can see these third party apps are white-listed in OS code and have some special permissions to do things.

According to this thread 
[How to create kiosk compatible chrome packaged app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956109/how-to-create-kiosk-compatible-chrome-packaged-app) In order to be white-listed Google must review your app for security.

I am not able to find any information or documentation on the internet to describe the procedure of how to submit apps to Google for app review. Any information regarding this would be appreciated, thanks.